# Как увеличить область отображаемого числа?

Tags: python

Только начал учить Python, и сделать калькулятор но тут он выдает ошибку которую я не могу никак найти

```
x = float(input())
y = float(input())
operation = str(input())

if operation == "+":
    print (x + y)
elif operation == "-":
    print (x - y)
elif operation == "/" and y != 0.0:
    print (x / y)
elif operation == "*":
    print (x * y)
elif operation == "mod" and y != 0.0:
    print (x // y and x % y)
elif operation == "pow":
    print (x ** y)
elif operation == "div" and y != 0.0:
    print (x % y)
if y == 0.0 and (operation in ('/', 'mod', 'div')):
    print('Деление на 0!')
```

Данные которые ввожу:

```
7
399
pow
```

Ошибка которую он выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 16, in <module>
    print (x ** y)
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

Как я понял, что данная ошибка указывает на то что максимум знаков которая она может показать это 34, но как увеличить этот максимум, я не понимаю

Comment: Вам не кажется что 399 степень - слишком много?)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/what-is-the-maximum-float-in-python

Comment: ну я не знаю в чем может быть ошибка, гуглил как мог, уже часа 3 потратил

Comment: В том, что устройство стандартных компьютерных вещестенных чисел таково, что они в принципе не могут содержать в себе настолько большие числа. Если вам прям очень-очень надо, то придётся использовать не float, а какой-то нестандартный тип чисел с длинной арифметикой

Comment: (вообще можно просто заменить float на int — он поддерживает длинную арифметику, но тогда, очевидно, получится вводить только целые числа)

Comment: int не подходить, тогда я не смогу делить float

Comment: вот она законамерность)

Comment: numpy.float128?

Comment: @eri а потом автор захочет возвести число 7 в степень 5837 )

Answer (score 0):

```py
from decimal import Decimal
x = 7
y = 399

try:
    result = x ** y
except OverflowError:
    result = Decimal('{:.2E}'.format(Decimal(x) ** Decimal(y)))
print(result)
# 1.56E+337
```

---

```py
from decimal import Decimal
x = 7
y = 20000

result = Decimal('{:.2E}'.format(Decimal(x) ** Decimal(y)))

print(result)
print(result / 50000000)
print(float(result))
# 9.14E+16901
# 1.828E+16894
# inf
```